# what is the FieldName that show ICollection data in GridControl.ItemsSource in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

i have object patient contains user object and it contain ICollection that  i wanna show them in GridControl  so I tried that   FieldName="User.Phone" but it show System.Collection.ObjectModle...

so how I can show ICollection Object in GridControl

```
<dxg:GridColumn VisibleIndex="2"
    FieldName="User.Phone"
    IsSmart="True"
    ReadOnly="True"
    MinWidth="120"
    Header="Phone" />
```

Comment: Where does `dxg` come from?

Comment: xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible variants:

- use converter for convert collection to semicolumn-separated string. (like "phone1; phone2; ... phoneN")
- define property in VM which will contains only default phone and use it in view.
- use CellTemplate for show collection in specific control (for example combobox or itemscontrol)

  ```
   <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="User">
       <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="PART_Editor" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Phone}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>    
   </dxg:GridColumn>
  ```

Comment: can u provide me some code because this code don't work and and I have table for each row I have this item I name it phone  this phone item I wanna to show on it iCollection  tathi fetch it from MySQL in Patient Object